# Why can't I initialize instances using for loop - Python, class

Tags: python, class, for-loop, instance

error: name 'w1' is not defined
I tried  to use for loop to initialize all the workers( w1, w2, w3) so i can access them afterwards. But when I try to access them they say the instance is not defined, is it possible that you cant initialize using for loop. Thanks in advance, beginner here.

```
   class Worker(object):
        
    
        def __init__(self, name, age):
             self.name=name
             self.age=age
    
    worker_list=["w1", "w2", "w3"]
    
    for i in worker_list:
        name=input("what is the worker's name?")
        age=input("What is the worker's age?")
        i=Worker(name, age)
        
    print(w1.name)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation so it's clear what you are trying to do. Are you attempting to instantiate class instances within the class definition or outside it?

Comment: Please can elaborate what you want to do

Comment: I think he wants w1, w2, w3 be the name of the variables assigned to the Worker objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age

worker_list=["w1", "w2", "w3"]

workers = {}

for worker in worker_list:
    name=input("what is the worker's name?")
    age=input("What is the worker's age?")
    object=Worker(name, age)
    workers[worker] = object

print(workers['w1'].name)
```

I think the best solution is to use a dictionary, create a empty dictionary, and for any element in your `worker_list` insert a key/value pair into the dictionary, where the key is the element of your `worker_list` so, `w1, w2, w3` and the value is the relative `Worker()` object.

This way you can retrieve your object using keys instead of anonymous numerical indeces.

Comment: Thanks man! this is much more organized, i can directly use w1 or w2 etc, much better. I initially thought when I use " for i in worker_list", the I is basically=w1, and from there it will initialized... apparently not... Thanks !

Comment: Declare variables like you initially wanted to do is not possible in Python, this is how close to it you can get.

Answer (score 1):

Define a new list where you want to append the new objects. Otherwise you cannot access all instantiations.

```
class Worker(object):
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name=name
    self.age=age

worker_list=["w1", "w2", "w3"]

new_workers = []

for objects in range(len(worker_list)):
    name=input("what is the worker's name?")
    age=input("What is the worker's age?")
    objects=Worker(name, age)
    new_workers.append(objects)

print(new_workers[0].name)
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the solution, it works! So basically, it is not possible for me to directly initialize the instance's variables by directly using for loop. Instead, I have to initialize then append to a new list then it will work? Am i correct?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the code posted by the author of the question is that you are trying to access a variable named  `w1`, which does not exist. In your for loop you only create `i`, so if you would use `print(i.name)` it would work. Nonetheless, I think the answer posted by DarknessPlusPlus improves your code even more.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I assume that when i use I it will automatically be w1=Worker(name,age), misconception here, thanks!